# Recommendations for extracting and archiving rows from a fast growing table to keep overall database size within 1tb limit

Tags: backup, azure-sql-database, azure

We have an Azure SQL DB that we want to keep less than 1TB in size because making a DB more than 1TB in Azure also requires doubling the vcores and therefore doubling the cost.

There is one table in the db that we write to constantly, resulting in billions of rows of data. Data over 6 months old in this table will very rarely if ever be accessed, so, we want to archive this data as cheaply as possible and extract it from the table in order to prevent our overall database size from reaching our 1TB limit.

What are our backup options for extracting and archiving just the oldest rows from this one table?

Our current thought is to have code running that reads the oldest 1 million rows, and appends it to a CSV file then deletes the rows from the original table. When the CSV file gets to (edit) approximately 10Gb (edit: making sure all current rows/data are written fully), we move the CSV file to archive storage for the cheapest possible costs.

Are there any other recommended approaches, or, in particular, are there SQL functions or process to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

### pre-ramble

I'm a little hesitant to answer this, because answering this type of question ends up being a lot more involved as additional considerations and details come out in comments. Hopefully I'm wrong, because Q&A is a bad format for a consulting engagement.

> Our current thought is to have code running that reads the oldest 1
> million rows, and appends it to a CSV file then deletes the rows from
> the original table. When the CSV file gets to 10Gb, we move the CSV
> file to archive storage for the cheapest possible costs.

This seems a bit over-engineered, error-prone, and confusing (why is this file only 9.9GB? Are we missing data?).

You're much better off creating a daily CSV and archiving those at a reasonable cadence that aligns with data retention policies defined by the business, or legal/compliance requirements. This way, there's no ambiguousness about *where* data is if you need to go back to get anything.

This also allows you to store metadata specific to each file in the database, like the number of rows moved, primary key values present and accounted for in the file, etc. Having that sort of handy lookup data also allows you to easily verify the results of your process.

> Are there any other recommended approaches, or, in particular, are
> there SQL functions or process to handle this situation?

You're going to read about partitioning, and you're going to develop a severe itch to partition this table, that neither God nor well-intentioned man will be able to easily talk you out of.

While you likely would benefit from it in some small way, applying partitioning to a table that is billions of rows would stress the server to its capacity, and beyond a maintenance window would allow for. You're already worried about hardware costs, here.

You'd be looking at redoing all of the indexes to align with the partition scheme, and removing any other offending elements (like foreign keys) that would prohibit partition switching.

It would theoretically allow you to quickly switch out all the rows that you're going to load into a CSV into a staging table with only minor locking, though. But that is all. It would not generally help performance in any other way.

I would avoid going this route, unless you enjoy *a lot* of pain. If you do, any reputable dungeon in your area would likely provide cheaper and less complicated access in meeting that particular drive (with the added benefit of supporting a local business).

Inevitably, someone will chime in with *you could always create a shadow copy of the table set up with partitioning and move all the data over to it in batches*, but that is evermore complicated than they'll let on, and doesn't help you control the size of the database in the interim.

### moving on

If you need anything beyond this, feel free to edit and update your original question with additional details that may help you get a more complete answer.